In Gin can I call something equivalent to context.bindJSON without setting HTTP status on failure
I have an API that uses Gin and I have a problem where a request may or may not include a JSON object and I don't want the request to fail if it does not.
I have been using context.bindJSON to retrieve the incoming JSON which works great if it is present, but if it is absent the Gin context sets the response code to 400 and once that response code is written there's nothing I can do to change it.
I do the marshalling in a simple generic function like this:
func marshalFromRequest[T any](ctx *gin.Context, logFailures bool) (*T, error) {
    var typed T
    if ctx.Request.ContentLength == 0 {
        return nil, nil
    }
    if err := ctx.BindJSON(&typed); err != nil {
        if logFailures {
            log.Printf("Cannot bind incoming data to type: %v", err)
        }
        return nil, err
    }
    return &typed, nil
}

What do I need to change to be able to parse out the JSON object if it exists but to be able to ignore the failure if it doesn't? If this worked in exactly the same way but didn't set the status code when the JSON is absent from the request I would be fine.

If you add if ctx.ContentType() != "application/json" {   return nil, nil  } after the content length checking, you can avoid this situation

You can use ContentType() to check if requests have JSON.
if ctx.ContentType() == gin.MIMEJSON {
  // request has JSON.
  err := ctx.BindJSON(&typed)
    :
} else {
  // request does not have JSON.
    :
}

